# Using instances from main module in other modules in Python

Tags: python, class, module, instance, share

I am currently restructuring my code with modules and facing a problem regarding instances.

So far I created 3 scripts: main_script.py, launchgui.py, steppermotors.py.

main_script should only create instances to launch the GUI and initialize stepper motor configuration etc.

As I need the instance GUI of launchgui.LaunchGui also in a method of the class StepperMotor I thought I could just create the instance in the same way I did in the main script. I also need the instance of StepperMotors() to call the method "calculate_angle()" within the LaunchGui class.

Unfortunately, the GUI doesn't start anymore when creating the same instances in every module and I also don't receive any error messages. 
Also I think this is not really best practice.

Therefore I wanted to ask if there is a "right" and working way to share instances with other modules that only have been created in the main script?

I hope you can help me with this!

See code snippets of the affected modules below:

**main_script.py**

```
import launchgui
import steppermotors
from tkinter import *

def main():
  root = Tk()
  gui = launchgui.LaunchGui(root)                                       #Creates instance 'gui' of the class 'LaunchGui' from the module 'launchgui' & initialises class    
  stepper = steppermotors.StepperMotors()                               #Creates instance 'stepper' of the class 'StepperMotors' from the module 'steppermotors' & initialises class
  root.mainloop()                                                       #Mainloop for tkinter-GUI
  ...
```

**launchgui.py**

```
#own modules
import steppermotors
#other modules
from tkinter import *

class LaunchGui:

   def __init__(self, root):
       ''' This function creates the gui with all buttons etc. 
           when initialising this class
       '''

       #Instances
       stepper = steppermotors.StepperMotors()  

       ...(Gui buttons etc. here)
       #Move to Position 
       btn_moveto_position = Button(control_frame, text='Move to Position', command=lambda:stepper.calculate_angle([0,0,0,0]))
       ...
```

**steppermotors.py**

```
#own modules
import launchgui
#other modules 
from tkinter import *

class StepperMotors:
''' This class contains the configuration and control algorithms for 
    the stepper motors (Axis1-4)
'''
    def __init__(self):                                                         
    ''' Setting Output-Pins, Microstep-Resolution, Transmission and
        Ramping parameters for the different motors when 
        initialising the class
    '''

    #Instances of other classes 
    root = Tk()
    gui = launchgui.LaunchGui(root)                                 #Creates instance 'gui' of the class 'LaunchGui' from the module 'launchgui'

    ...(some other functions here)

    def calculate_angle(self, previous_angles_list):
    ''' This function calculates the difference (=delta) between
        the current and previous slider_values (=angle)
    '''
    #Current angles 
    current_angles_list = []                                        #Creates empty list to append current values
    delta_angles_list = []                                          #Creates empty list to append difference between current and previous angles (=delta)

    for idx in range(self.number_of_motors):                            #Looping through list indices (idx)
        current_angles_list.append(gui.SLIDER_list[idx].get())      #Appends currently selected slidervalues (=current angle) to current_angles_list
        deltas_list.append(int(current_angles_list[idx] -       
                                previous_angles_list[idx]))         #Calculates the difference between current and previous angle as an integer and appends it to delta list
```

Comment: have you called main() function?

Comment: Okey - I found out why my GUI isn't starting anymore (stupid me).

I got stuck in an endless loop where the creation of the launchgui instance is calling the steppermotor initialisation which is then calling launchgui initialisation again.

Still didn't find another way to do it...

Comment: Yes, I did call main() - sorry, didn't include this part in my snippet here.